# How to add static file(css, images, js etc..) to our node js application?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, backend

This is my project folder structure:

```
XYZ_PROJECT_FOLDER

  ASSETS
    CSS
    IMAGES
    JS
    VENDOR

  CONTACT.html
  INDEX.html
  INDEX.js
```

And this is the code inside the INDEX.js file to render all the static files and other routing code:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    const multiparty = require("multiparty");
    require("dotenv").config();
    
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.static('assets'));
    
    app.route("/").get(function (req,res){
        res.sendFile(process.cwd()+"/index.html")
    })
    
    app.route("/contact").get(function (req,res){
        res.sendFile(process.cwd()+"/contact-form.html")
    })
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
    });
```

Whenever I run the command "node INDEX.js" it works all fine but it is not rendering any css, image, or js scripts any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have [Express serve static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to resolve this. Here's an example:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey so the issue was in the HTML code I was using the whole path i.e. assets/css/style.css instead of using /css/style.css

changed the path in HTML and it worked.